# Access denied while calling external URL ajax call

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-addin, jquery, ajax

I got the access denied error when i am calling external URL from Ajax call. it is working fine without SharePoint 2010.

```
 <script>
    function httpGet(theUrl) {
        debugger;
        var xmlHttp = null;
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlHttp.open("GET","http://ip.jsontest.com/", false);
        xmlHttp.send(null);
        alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
        var obj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        alert(obj.ip);
        return xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
</script>
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: Isn't this normal [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)? Unless that site has CORS enabled. There are ways to solve this, such as CORS, JSONP or app proxy.

Comment: i had also tried with jsonp but still its not working

Comment: Note that the server must implement support for JSONP, it is not automatically given that the server in your example supports this.

Comment: can you give me some idea that how can i implement support for JSONP

Comment: Understanding how the JSONP _hack_ actually works would give you a good idea. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2067584) on SO should give a good explanation. If it is your server then do consider my two other suggestions as well (CORS and web proxy).

Comment: @eirikb, I don't think `SP.WebRequestInfo()` is available in SP 2010?

Comment: no without sp2010 means i have checked in html

Comment: @RajeshJoshi, you should probably remove sharepoint apps tag in the question. It is misleading as you are working on SP 2010.

Comment: i have added it because it mainly depends on JavaScript so they have knowledge about it